# Parse - offline object crash

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform

I'm having some trouble with Parse SDK for Android. I can't reproduce the issue, but from the logs I know it happens when I call

```
bookParse.saveEventually { ex -> ... }
```

The exception is:

```
Attempted to fetch an object offline which was never saved to the offline cache.
```

The main problem is that before I call saveEventually, I do a `bookParse.pin()`. Should I do anything extra?

As well, this is not an insert of the BookParse object, it's an update I do after the object was queried like this:

```
val query = ParseQuery.getQuery(BookParse::class.java)
query.fromNetwork()
query.whereEqualTo("localId", localId)
query.getFirstInBackground { bookParse, ex ->
    //do stuff to bookParse
    bookParse.pin()
    bookParse.saveEventually { ex -> ... }
}
```